# Display Exact Same Text on Another Text Box

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-selected-items

May I know how can I display the exact same value from the first Combobox filter list on Screen1, and display the same value without needing to select again?

Appreciate your help.

[image]

Comment: how does this relate to Power Query? Please don't crowd your question with all kinds of tags. Use only those relevant to your topic.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a text box, it's a dropdown. That's a difference. You need to set the default value for the control and point it to the current value of the control on the other screen.

If the dropdown control on the left is called `MyDropdown1`, then you can use this as the default value in the dropdown control on the right:

`MyDropdown1.Selected.Value`

The exact syntax may be a little bit different, depending on the data source of the dropdown.

Of course, you can avoid all that by using only one screen instead of several screens. Show and hide elements of the screen based on field values and leave the dropdown at the top visible at all times.

Comment: Hi Teylyn, appreciate a lot for the reply. Initially, it still showed an error and I realized I didn't put open and close bracket [ ]. So far it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the control on Screen2 to a TextBox.
2. Set `OnChange` property of Screen1 Dropdown to:
   `Set(varVehicle, dropdown1.Selected.Value`
3. Set `Default` property of Screen2 Textbox control to: `varVehicle`